# Attack from different blacklisted IP which belongs to different GEO location

Tags: siem

Attack from different blacklisted IP which belongs to different GEO location although source MAC address is same. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **source MAC that you see is *always* going to be the MAC address of your router** that's sending the packet along the last hop.  MAC addresses aren't routed; they're only visible between the two devices handing the packet to each other.

Given a packet routed from A to D via routers B and C:

```
[A] --> [B] ---> [C] --> [D]
```

- B will see A as the source MAC address.
- C will see B as the source MAC address.
- D will see C as the source MAC address.

---

Given the MAC address of 00:00:CA:00:00:03 that the OP has provided in the comments:

The first three bytes are the Vendor ("Organizationally Unique Identifier", or "OUI").  These can be looked up to determine who manufactured the ethernet card you're seeing:

[Wireshark OUI Lookup Tool](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) says: `00:00:CA ARRIS Group, Inc.`

If you Google ARRIS Group their [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arris_Group) page is the third hit:

> Arris Group is an American telecommunications equipment manufacturing
>   company that provides cable operators with high-speed data, video and
>   telephony systems for homes and businesses....
>
> ...
>
> Two of the company's popular home telephony modems are the TM402P and
>   the TM502G. The firm also produces the SBG6782-AC wireless cable
>   modem-and-router (residential gateway) unit, among other
>   telecommunications and data-transfer products.

In other words, they make cable modems, which are the routers that your Cable company uses to provide Internet to your Firewall.

Comment: My Scenario:
My devices & computers are behind the firewall. I am seeing firewall log. In firewall log I am seeing same mac addressees.

Comment: I am talking about external traffic which comes in my network.

Comment: Yes.  The firewall will only ever see the MAC address of the device that handed it the packet, which is the router outside the firewall.

Comment: Yes, It's one possibility. Any other possibility?
00:00:CA:00:00:03 is like unusual.

Comment: @NishitDholakiya Completely normal - see update to answer.